# How to add a multiplier in the convolution function?

Tags: convolution, correlation

*I shall write my questions first:*

---

**1. Is there any other simple and efficient method in Mathematica that can compute the convolution of two or more random variables with correlation?**

**2. How to modify the build-in convolution function and adds a copula multiplier in it?**

**3. How to compute a multivariable convolution consider the dependence among variables?**

---

*For people who want to know the background of these questions:*

---

I found an interesting work in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GvPb.png), where a copula multiplier is added to the traditional convolution and thus presents a novel convolution method that holds under correlated random variables. The idea comes from the definition of the copula. A convolution with two correlated random variables $\alpha$ and $\beta$ can be computed as:

$f_{\alpha +\beta}(a) = \int_{\underline{\alpha }}^{\bar{\alpha }} f_{\alpha }(x) f_{\beta }(a-x) c\left(F_{\alpha
   }(x),F_{\beta }\left(a-x\right)\right) \, dx$

where $f_{\alpha }(x)$ and $f_{\beta}(x)$ are the PDF of the random variables, $F_{\alpha}(x)$ and $F_{\beta}(x)$ are the CDF of these two random variables, $c$ denotes the PDF of copula function. If we denote the PDF for the sum of these two variables as $f_{\alpha }(x)+f_{\beta}(x)=f_{\alpha +\beta}(z)$. Then the former equation gives the PDF value of $f_{\alpha +\beta}$ when $ z=a$.

Although I have a doubt on the accuracy of its result and the preciseness for the copula PDF used in the formulation. It truly presents a way to compute the convolution of two (or more) correlated random variables.

However, after testing the attached codes for correlated bivariate convolution, I found it is not easy to code this method with Mathematica, especially in the multivariable scenarios.

---

The approach presented in [2] can be regarded as a supplement of [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GvPb.png).

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GvPb.png) N. Zhang, C. Kang, C. Singh, and Q. Xia, "*Copula Based Dependent Discrete Convolution for Power System Uncertainty Analysis*," IEEE Transactions on Power Systems, vol. 31, no. 6, pp. 5204-5205, 2016.

[2] Y. Wang, N. Zhang, C. Kang, M. Miao, R. Shi, and Q. Xia, "*An Efficient Approach to Power System Uncertainty Analysis With High-Dimensional Dependencies*," IEEE Transactions on Power Systems, vol. 33, no. 3, pp. 2984-2994, 2018.

```
(* The inputs here are
        Discerte probabilities 
            |  discerte xlables   
            |         |      fitted copula kernel (Marginal = UniformDistribution[])
            \[DownArrow]         \[DownArrow]                \[DownArrow]  *)
CopulaConv[Pa_,Pb_,xlableA_,xlableB_,cop_] :=

Module[{na = Length[Pa],nb= Length[Pb], copPDF, Pz, i, j, step, newxlable},
(* Functions we need *)
getAxisMin[lableA_,lableB_] := -(Abs@lableA[[1]]+Abs@lableB[[1]]);
getAxisMax[lableA_,lableB_] := Abs@lableA[[-1]]+Abs@lableB[[-1]];
CopulaKernel[copula_,Nx_,Ny_] := Table[PDF[copula,{x,y}],{x,Range[1/Nx,1-1/Nx,1/Nx]},{y,Range[1/Ny,1-1/Ny,1/Ny]}];
(*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*)

(* recover the steps *)
step = xlableA[[2]]-xlableA[[1]];

(* make a new coordinate [Underscript[\[Alpha], _]+Underscript[\[Beta], _], Overscript[\[Alpha], _]+Overscript[\[Beta], _]], to locate the new distribution *)
newxlable = Range[getAxisMin[xlableA,xlableB],getAxisMax[xlableA,xlableB],step];

(* The PDF of copula is prepared*)
copPDF = CopulaKernel[cop,Length[xlableA],Length[xlableB]];

(* Initialize *)
Pz = Table[0,Length[newxlable]-1]; 

For[ i=1, i<=na, i++,
      (*Pz[[i;;(i+nb-1)]]= Pz[[i;;(i+nb-1)]]+Pa[[i]]*Pb;*)
      (* for dependent model with copula, we have: *)
       Pz[[i;;(i+nb-1)]] = Pz[[i;;(i+nb-1)]]+copPDF[[i,All]]*Pa[[i]]*Pb;
];

(*Normalize the probability*)
Pz/Total[Pz];
{Pz,newxlable}]
```

```
TransToDiscrete[dist_,boxes_] := Module[{datatemp,sampleNum,axislable,prob}, (*Get the probability value of each discrete blocks*)
                                sampleNum = 10^5;
                                datatemp = RandomVariate[dist, sampleNum];
                                {axislable,prob} = HistogramList[datatemp,boxes];
                                prob = prob/sampleNum;{axislable,prob}];
```

```
rebuildPMF[xlable_,Prob_] := Piecewise[Append[Table[{Prob[[i]],xlable[[i]]<= # <xlable[[i+1]]},{i,1,Length[Prob]}],{0,True}]]&
```

```
distA = NormalDistribution[];
distB = NormalDistribution[3,1];
copula = CopulaDistribution[{"Binormal",0.7},{UniformDistribution[],UniformDistribution[]}];

{xlableA,Pa} = TransToDiscrete[distA,20]//N;
{xlableB,Pb} = TransToDiscrete[distB,20]//N;
```

```
(* Discrete Dependent Convolution *)
(* for a finite list/sequence *)
{Pzz,newxlable} = CopulaConv[Pa,Pb,xlableA,xlableB,copula];

(* Compare with traditional convulation, without correlation *)
ListConvolve[Pa,Flatten[Pb],{1,-1},0];
```

```
distZ = TransformedDistribution[x+y,{x,y}\[Distributed]BinormalDistribution[{0,3},{1,1},0.7]];
Plot[{rebuildPMF[xlableA,Pa][i],rebuildPMF[xlableB,Pb][i],rebuildPMF[newxlable,Pzz][i]},{i,-5,10},Filling->Axis,PlotLabel->"DDC",PlotLegends->{"a~N(0,1)","b~N(3,1)","a+b"}]
Plot[{PDF[distA,x],PDF[distB,x],PDF[distZ,x]},{x,-5,10},PlotLegends->{"a~N(0,1)","b~N(3,1)","a+b"},PlotLabel->"Actual value"]
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to Mathematica.SE. Then, 1. What do you mean by "I found it is not easy to reproduce this method with Mathematica"? You fail to reproduce the algorithm with _Mathematica_, or you fail to reproduce it in an efficient way, or something else? 2. Is it necessary for us to read 2+10 pages of paper to understand the question? If so, I'm afraid the question is out of scope of this site. If not, please include all the background infomation necessary for understanding your problem in the body of your question to keep it self-contained.

Comment: Thank you xzczd, I have rewritten the question to make it self-contained.  Actually, I think one can understand and answer the question without context.

Comment: What are $\underline{\alpha }$ and $\bar{\alpha}$?